# How can I split R dataframe rows into multiple rows based on a condition?

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr

If my data resembles this:

```
  Variable 1   Variable 2   Variable 3
1   Red|Blue      0|1          1|0
2   Blue|Red      1|0          0|1
3   Green|Red     0|1          1|0
4   Yellow|Blue   1|0          0|1
```

What might I use to separate based on the "|"? Something like this:

```
 Variable 1   Variable 2   Variable 3
1   Red           0            1
2   Blue          1            0
3   Blue          1            0
4   Red           0            1
5   Green         0            1
6   Red           1            0
7   Yellow        1            0
8   Blue          0            1
```

Comment: check out `tidyr::separate_rows()`. E.g., `separate_rows(df, everything(), sep = "\\|")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `separate_rows`

```
> df %>% 
   separate_rows(., Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
  <chr>         <int>     <int>
1 Red               0         1
2 Blue              1         0
3 Blue              1         0
4 Red               0         1
5 Green             0         1
6 Red               1         0
7 Yellow            1         0
8 Blue              0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3"), sep="|", "long")
#   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#1:       Red         0         1
#2:      Blue         1         0
#3:      Blue         1         0
#4:       Red         0         1
#5:     Green         0         1
#6:       Red         1         0
#7:    Yellow         1         0
#8:      Blue         0         1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Variable1 = c("Red|Blue", "Blue|Red", "Green|Red", 
"Yellow|Blue"), Variable2 = c("0|1", "1|0", "0|1", "1|0"), Variable3 = c("1|0", 
"0|1", "1|0", "0|1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```